# C - Reading multiple ints and one str from a file into a Linked List

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a project which will allow users to store data on a file and then withdraw it. As an intermediary, I'm using doubly linked lists. This way, it'll operate like this:

Input -> to List -> to File

File -> to List -> to Output

I find myself having trouble getting the file back into the list, however. This is the list itself:

```
typedef struct Inode2*Task;                                     
typedef struct Inode2{
        int ID;
        int Priority;
        int Status;
        char *Description;
        Person *person;
        Date   *creation;
        Date   *deadline;
        Date   *conclusion;                             
        Task next;
        Task previous;
    }Task_node2;
```

With this structure, I'm using the following function to write it into the last position of the linked list:

```
void TaskInsertTail(Task h,int ID,char*DESC,int PRIORITY,Date*DATAINICIO,Date*DATAPRAZO,Date*DATAFIM,int STATUS)            {
    Task aux=(Task)malloc(sizeof(Task_node2));
    aux->ID=ID;
    aux->Status = STATUS;
    aux->Description = DESC;
    aux->Priority = PRIORITY;
    aux->creation = DATAINICIO;
    aux->deadline = DATAPRAZO;
    aux->conclusion = DATAFIM;
    aux->next=NULL;
    if(!h->next)
    {
        h->next=h->previous=aux;
    }
    else
    {
        aux->previous=h->previous;
        aux->previous->next=aux;
        h->previous=aux;
    }
}
```

And, last but not least, before the FILE stuff begins, the Printing function:

```
void TaskPrint(Task h)                                                                              {
    h=h->next;
    while(h!=NULL)
    {
        printf("ID:%d PRIO:%d STATUS:%d DESC:%s",h->ID,h->Priority,h->Status,h->Description);
        printf("Criada:%.2d/%.2d/%.4d - Prazo:%.2d/%.2d/%.4d - ",h->creation->Day,h->creation->Month,h->creation->Year,h->deadline->Day,h->deadline->Month,h->deadline->Year);
        if (h->conclusion->Year==0)
            printf("Por concluir");
        else
            printf("Concluida:%.2d/%.2d/%.4d",h->conclusion->Day,h->conclusion->Month,h->conclusion->Year);
        h=h->next;
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
```

All those functions work pretty well in an isolated environment, they add the element correctly, they distribute the variables nicely and it all works, generally speaking.

The problems begin when I try to from the file that contains them. Here's the files' structure:

```
561 1 1 10 10 10 10 10 10 0 0 0 FirstTask1

562 2 1 20 20 20 20 20 20 0 0 0 SecondTask2

563 3 1 30 30 30 30 30 30 0 0 0 ThirdTask3

564 4 1 40 40 40 40 40 40 0 0 0 FourthOne4
```

And here's the File->Task function, as it is written in int_main():

```
int main(){
    Task TASK = TaskCreate();
    FILE * database;
    int i=0;
    char buffer[100];
    database = fopen("tasks.txt","r");
    if (NULL == database){perror("opening database file");exit(0);}
    while(!feof(database)){ 
        Date *D1=DateCreate();Date *D2=DateCreate();Date *D3=DateCreate();
        int ID, PRIO, STATUS;
        char DESC[100];
        int D1Day,D1Month,D1Year, D2Day,D2Month,D2Year, D3Day,D3Month,D3Year;
        fscanf(database,"%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",&ID,&PRIO,&STATUS,&D1Day,&D1Month,&D1Year, &D2Day,&D2Month,&D2Year, &D3Day,&D3Month,&D3Year); 
        fgets(DESC,101,database);
        D1->Day=D1Day;D1->Month=D1Month;D1->Year=D1Year;
        D2->Day=D2Day;D2->Month=D2Month;D2->Year=D2Year;
        D3->Day=D3Day;D3->Month=D3Month;D3->Year=D3Year;
        TaskInsertTail(TASK,ID,DESC,PRIO,D1,D2,D3,STATUS);
    }
    TaskPrint(TASK);//TST
    fclose(database); 
    return(0);
}
```

Despite it being a bit messy, it should work perfectly. I find, however, that it produces an extra element on the list, a duplicate of the second-to-last. Here's how it turned out when I ran it:

```
ID:561 PRIO:1 STATUS:1 DESC: FourthOne4
Criada:10/10/0010 - Prazo:10/10/0010 - Por concluir

ID:562 PRIO:2 STATUS:1 DESC: FourthOne4
Criada:20/20/0020 - Prazo:20/20/0020 - Por concluir

ID:563 PRIO:3 STATUS:1 DESC: FourthOne4
Criada:30/30/0030 - Prazo:30/30/0030 - Por concluir

ID:564 PRIO:4 STATUS:1 DESC: FourthOne4
Criada:40/40/0040 - Prazo:40/40/0040 - Por concluir

ID:564 PRIO:4 STATUS:1 DESC: FourthOne4
Criada:40/40/0040 - Prazo:40/40/0040 - Por concluir
```

So, observations:

Duplicated the last element (thinking about a loop that shouldn't be there);
Messed up the DESC element, basically overwriting the other ones with the last one;
My question is, how do I fix this? My belief is that I'm messing something up with the fgets() and I should be reading the DESC string using the fscanf(), but every attempt of mine to do so has failed. I'm not fully aware of how any of those functions operates, my class wasn't very detailed on it, I was just told to use them, and my own research has been inconsequential, as I've gained no understanding of them or anything of the sort.

Lastly, this is the output I'm trying to get:

```
ID:561 PRIO:1 STATUS:1 DESC: FirstTask1
Criada:10/10/0010 - Prazo:10/10/0010 - Por concluir

ID:562 PRIO:2 STATUS:1 DESC: SecondTask2
Criada:20/20/0020 - Prazo:20/20/0020 - Por concluir

ID:563 PRIO:3 STATUS:1 DESC: ThirdTask3
Criada:30/30/0030 - Prazo:30/30/0030 - Por concluir

ID:564 PRIO:4 STATUS:1 DESC: FourthOne4
Criada:40/40/0040 - Prazo:40/40/0040 - Por concluir
```

---

Any help is greatly appreciated, even if just to get a grip on what I'm doing, as I've hit my first dead end in this project, and it's been holding me back for hours...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to add in the DateCreate and TaskCreate functions. They are similiar so I'll just post the TaskCreate one:

```
Task TaskCreate()                                                                                   {
    Task aux=(Task)malloc(sizeof(Task));
    aux->next=NULL;
    aux->previous=NULL;
    return aux;
}
```

Comment: You are doing this `h->next=h->previous=aux;` i.e if the next node is empty, the next node points to the previous, which become pointing to aux (current last)

Comment: @Malina I see what you're saying. The function inserts an auxiliary 2list as the last node in another list2. So, it's working as intended, I believe.

Comment: Test your code with one list data only. Like an int for example. If the problem continues, post the SUPER SHORTIFIED version here, I will test myself and see the problem. This is very bad implementation of linked lists, not just messy.

Comment: @Malina I'll do that. I have to use this struct however, as it is mandatory for the assignment, so I'm in a bind...

Comment: Yes at the end you will use the same structure. Though it will be better to declare it as a separate structure so that your list only contains 3 pointers. The prev/next link and the data pointer.

But for now, a good debugging approach is to simplify and shorten your code as much as possible. Then it also becomes easier to edit and maintain.

Comment: Got rid of eof and used a check for first int read, and it's working alot better now. After using the memory allocation on the aux->description, it looks perfectly functional! I think it still needs alot of cleaning up! Thank you all so much, will report back!